# Does a company allow its employees to roll over their 401K money to an external IRA account while being employed?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, fidelity

If a person want's to transfer his/her 401K money to an external traditional IRA account (say Chase) while he is still employed at the company, will his company permit that? The employee might wanna continue to contribute to his 401K to get the company's matching amount and roll over some amount every year to the external traditional IRA account.
Is this something allowed?

Comment: Obviously, the answer to this question is, "**Ask Employer’s HR Department.**"

Comment: Call the 401(k) provider. You should be able to see the phone number once you log into the account. I asked before, and the answer was no for me.

Comment: To the close voters: This question is not seeking product or service recommendations. Please do not select that as the close reason for this question.

Comment: In-service rollover of contributions is a very rare feature for a 401k plan.  If you rolled money from a previous 401k, it’s typical that you can roll those funds back out though, just not anything related to contributions made while you were employed at the employer sponsoring your current 401k

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica IBM's 401(k) policy in June 2021 might not be it's 401(k) policy in July 2021.

Comment: @RonJohn And tax laws can change over time as well. That fact does not make this a product recommendation request.

Comment: I don't know what a valid close reason *would* be, but it certainly seems like this is more a question about IBM corporate policy that it is about personal finance.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I didn't vote to close the question but downvoted it instead. As the pop-box tells us about downvotes, the question does not show any research effort on the part of the OP, and RonJohn's comment as well as your own answer to the question effectively points this out. The OP has since then exerted himself enough to edit the question more  general by removing the reference to IBM, his employer, but presumably not enough to actually call IBM's HR Department. I see no reason to remove my downvote as yet.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I’m not questioning your downvote. However, if your objection was the naming of the employer, that has been removed by the OP. And you don’t really know whether or not the OP has called HR yet.

Answer (score 8):

There are many things that an employer can customize about its 401(k) plan, and the feature to allow participants to rollover funds out of the plan while still employed is one of those things. You’ll need to ask your company’s HR department to find out if this is allowed under your 401(k) plan’s rules.

Comment: I think you mean "to allow participants *over the age of 55* to roll funds out of the plan while still employed"?

Comment: @BenVoigt According to [this article from Ameriprise](https://www.ameriprise.com/financial-goals-priorities/retirement/should-you-roll-over-401k-to-ira-while-still-working): “the majority of 401(k) plans allow employees to roll over funds while they are still working.”

Comment: Well that page is very general and doesn't get into the restrictions at all.  Here is a better source: "For example, rolling over savings from a 401k plan to a traditional IRA is allowed by law if the money being moved is from employer contributions (either matched money or profit-sharing accumulations). The money being rolled over cannot come from pre-tax contributions unless the employee is 59½ years old or older. "  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inservicewithdrawal.asp

Comment: @BenVoigt Good article. Bottom line, there are lots of details, and even when you find out what is allowed by law, you still need to find out what is allowed by your employer’s plan.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that I know of in the government rules and regulations that would prohibit a transfer to your IRA while you are still employed.

However, your ability to transfer money out is subject to the rules of the plan. Those rules are written by people that want to manage your money. As such, they can and usually do restrict you from moving money out of your 401(k) plan.

I would ask the HR department or the person that administers the 401(k) plan but I would expect the answer to be no.